# ios: What is the best way to replace multiple strings in file by doing only one time replacement?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, replace

I have a file in which exist string on different places, I want to replace all those strings. e.g I have "too taa tii" and I want to replace [too] by [tee] and [tii] by [tuu]. As I know, I need to do twice.

Is there any other solution that I can do just only once??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think these line of code do this:-

```
NSString *mainString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"too taa tii"];
    NSArray *stringsToReplace = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"too",@"tii", nil];
    NSArray *stringsReplaceBy = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"tee",@"tuu", nil];
    for (int i =0; i< [stringsReplaceBy count]; i++)
    {
        mainString = [mainString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[stringsToReplace objectAtIndex:i] withString:[stringsReplaceBy objectAtIndex:i]];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and answered but an alternative is with NSDictionary

```
NSDictionary *replaceDict = @{@"too":@"tee", @"tii": @"tuu"};
for (NSString *replace in replaceDict) {
    mainString = [mainString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:replace withString:replaceDict[replace]];
}
```